# Flutter: testing shared preferences

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dart, flutter

I'm trying to test this function:

```
 void store(String x, String y) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'x': x,
      'y': y,
    };
    var jsonString = json.encode(map);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('fileName', jsonString);
  }
```

I saw that I can populate the shared preferences with

```
const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences')
  .setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    if (methodCall.method == 'getAll') {
      return <String, dynamic>{}; // set initial values here if desired
    }
    return null;
  });
```

But I didn't understand how to use, expecially in my case.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues` for your test

```
test('Can Create Preferences', () async{

    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({}); //set values here
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool working = false;
    String name = 'john';
    pref.setBool('working', working);
    pref.setString('name', name);


    expect(pref.getBool('working'), false);
    expect(pref.getString('name'), 'john');
  });
```

Comment: I keep getting errors when trying to test `shared_preferences`. Is it because I am running `flutter test` and not using a device to test?

Comment: No. You should be able to use it in flutter test.  What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I got it handled, I can't remember what the issue was though. Thank you!

Comment: I have an error : "Used on a non-mockito object" if I use `verify(pref.setString(any, any)).called()`

Comment: Yeah. It won't work with mockito. mockito expects an object that extends Mock like `class MockSharedPreference extends Mock implements SharedPreferences{}`. I don't really know how to make this work.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to nonybrighto for the helpful answer.

I ran into trouble trying to set initial values in shared preferences using:

```
SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({
  "key": "value"
});
```

It appears that the shared_preferences plugin expects keys to have the prefix `flutter.`. This therefore needs adding to your own keys if mocking using the above method.

See line 20 here for evidence of this:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/2ea4bc8f8b5ae652f02e3db91b4b0adbdd499357/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences/lib/shared_preferences.dart

Comment: The link above is broken

Comment: Thanks @SimonH - updated with link to new file location.

Comment: its not required. it automatically prefix the key: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/2ea4bc8f8b5ae652f02e3db91b4b0adbdd499357/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences/lib/shared_preferences.dart#L192

Comment: @HashemAboonajmi is right, your answer doesn't apply to the revision you linked (nor to the most recent one)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that helps you but I also lost a lot of time before finding this solution

**LocalDataSourceImp.test.dart**

```
void main(){
  SharedPreferences? preference;
  LocalDataSourceImp? localStorage ;

setUp(() async{
  preference =  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  localStorage = LocalDataSourceImp(preference!);
  SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
});

final token = TokenModel(data: "babakoto");

test("cache Token ", ()async{
  localStorage!.cacheToken(token);
  final result = preference!.getString(TOKEN);
  expect(result, json.encode(token.toJson()));
});
}
```

**LocalDataSourceImp.dart**

```
class LocalDataSourceImp implements LocalDataSource{

  SharedPreferences pref ;

  LocalDataSourceImp(this.pref);


  @override
  Future<void> cacheToken(TokenModel token)async {
    await pref.setString(TOKEN,json.encode(token));
  }

}
```

Comment: Where does `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});` come from? I get "Undefined name" for it...

Comment: testing code https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please include that information in your Answer, so that it's complete and runnable! 

Answer (score 2):

add this `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` in main function, solved for me