# Flutter - widget test never finishes on Linux

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, ubuntu, flutter-test

I use Flutter on Linux(Ubuntu). I created simply Linux desktop app. Also I created test widget, but I have issue. I have two user case:
first I run my application. after that I run the test, I always get the error:

```
   /home/ubuntu/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color test --machine --start- 
   paused 
   test/widget_test.dart
   Testing started at 10:00 AM ...

   package:flutter_tools/src/test/flutter_tester_device.dart 224:73  
   FlutterTesterTestDevice.finished
   ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
   dart:async/future.dart                                            Future.any.onValue

   Failed to load "/home/ubuntu/StudioProjects/my-flutter/test/widget_test.dart": Shell 
   subprocess ended cleanly. Did main() call exit()?
```

For fix it I running these commands :

```
   flutter clean
   flutter pub get
```

I run test(two user case) but it never ends - infinite loading indicator

[image]

This is my code, it working on Windows:

```
 testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) 
  async 
  {
   final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   await tester.pumpWidget(ProviderScope(overrides: [
   settingsProvider.overrideWithValue(
    SettingsService(pref),
   ),
  ], child: const MyApp()));
  expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

 });
```

is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Can you upload the widget_test.dart code and the widget's code?

Comment: If I remember correctly, SharedPreferences saves its data on a file in Linux. If another process is accessing that file, it has to wait for that process to release the lock so that it can access the file. This is probably why you're test is taking so long. You might want to take a look at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences/test/shared_preferences_test.dart and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793716/flutter-testing-shared-preferences to mock SharedPreferences

Comment: Thank you. the reason was in the settings. you can frame this as an answer

Comment: Its ok, I'll leave it as a comment. Glad it helped